# Unable to extract specific class of webpage

Tags: vba, http, data-extraction

We are currently extracting data from below mentioned site.Our code is extracting data properly but we are unable to extract description class data.My code is given below.I want to extract following url from trailing page("https://www.skroutz.gr/mp/68997450/All-Star-Chuck-Taylor-Ox-M7652C.html"

```
http.Open "GET", "https://www.skroutz.gr/s/4706923/Converse-All-Star-Chuck-Taylor-Ox-M7652C.html", False                         
http.Send                                           
html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText             
html1 = html.body.innerHTML                         
brand = html.body.innerText                         
html1 = html.body.innerHTML                         
html3 = html.documentElement.innerHTML              
html3 = Replace(html3, """", "")                    
html2 = Replace(html1, """", "")                    
Set tdt = html.getElementsByClassName("description")
For Each Item In tdt                                
href = Item.getElementsByTagName("a")               
Exit For                                            
Next
```

Comment: Maybe `href = Item.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)`  since that's still a collection, even if there's only one matching element found.

Comment: you want the href attribute presumably as well rather than the a tag. You want SET if after the node.

Comment: If you are after the products links then it looks like you want Dim links As Object: Set links =  html.querySelectorAll("h3 .js-product-link") then loop that For i = 0 To links.length - 1 and extract link.item(i).href within loop. It would be helpful to state some of the expected output.

Comment: But when we are checking source code then links are not visible

Comment: Following code is extracting null values.Dim links As Object
Set links = html.querySelectorAll("h3 .js-product-link")
For ii = 0 To links.length - 1
href1 = link.Item(ii).href
Fileout.write href1
Next ii

Comment: links are probably part of dynamic content not available from original url. Check the network tab of browser or elsewhere in current response to see if you can find the source

Comment: new url not visible in network tab,did you check?

Comment: yes... it is present in the POST request to https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/product_prices.json

Comment: thanks,then how to query this part in code.